# Evalaute indefinite integral of $2x(4x+7)^8$.

Tags: integration

I've just started doing calculus, this is an assignment question which I'm having trouble with. Any help showing the steps would be much appreciated!

$$\int2x(4x+7)^8 \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: You may want to reword your question a bit, as you probably meant "complicated" when you wrote "complex", as the latter term can mislead people into believing it has something to do with complex numbers. Also, in general, you'd want to write $\int 2x(4x+7)^8 dx$ in the future, instead of $\int 2x(4x+7)^8$, so as to mark what variable you're supposed to integrate with respect to.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

let $$u = 4x + 7$$ $$2x = \frac{u-7}{2}$$

$$\frac{du}{dx} = 4$$

$$ \int 2x(4x+7)^8dx = \int \frac{u-7}{2}u^8\frac{du}{4} $$

$$ \int \frac{u^9-7u^8}{8}du = \int \frac{u^9}{8}du - \int\frac{7u^8}{8} du$$

$$ $$

Can you do this now? Once you've integrated wrt. u, rewrite your answer in terms of $x$ by substituting $u$ with $4x+7$

Answer (score 1):

Since you just started calculus, let us consider the general problem of $$I=\int a\,x\,(bx+c)^n\,dx=a\int x\,(bx+c)^n\,dx$$ where $n\neq -1$.

In the same spirit as answers you already received, change variable such that $$bx+c=y$$ that is to say $$x=\frac{y-c}b$$ $$dx=\frac 1b dy$$ and now let us replace $$I=a\int \frac{y-c}b \,y^n\, \frac 1b\, dy=\frac{a}{b^2}\int (y-c)\,y^n\,dy=\frac{a}{b^2}\Big(\int y^{n+1}\,dy-c\int y^n \,dy\Big)$$ where you are left with the simplest possible antiderivatives. After integration, replace $y$ by $bx+c$ in the answer.

**Edit**

As Idris commented, do not forget to add the integration constant !

Comment: I Will add to the end of Claude's. ...and don't forget integration constant.

Comment: @Idris. **YES**, I forgot this one. I shall add it to my answer. Thanks !

Comment: mybe it is good to specify that $n$ should be different from -1. Otherwise it is too general comparing to the asked question